# Use Case Diagram: Too many <<include>> relationships

Tags: uml, modeling, use-case

I'm not sure if my diagram is correct. Is it ok to have this number of `<<include>>` relationships?

**Note**: My system scenario: The user goes to the web page and enters any Twitter user account, then my system will collect the desired user's tweets, clean and pre-process them, classify them, calculate the classification result, and finally display the result to the user.

[image: Use Case Diagram]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Is it about the use case diagram ?

Use case shall give the big picture of the system under consideration, by showing what it is used for and how it brings value to the actors in its environment.

The "[value](https://www.pmi.org/learning/library/use-cases-project-manager-know-8262)" concept is essential for the identification of the use cases: the intent here is not to describe in detail how the system shall behave, nor its internal interactions. It's about the purpose. Each use case in the diagram shall be:

> the description of a set of sequences of actions and variants that a
> system performs that yield an observable result of value to an actor.
>  - Ivar Jacobson

Let's apply this to your example:  *collect tweets*, *clean tweets*, *pre-process tweets*, *classify tweets* and *calculate results* all seem to be steps that, have no observable result and no value to the user if taken separately. Similarly, *display results* is not an independent use case either: it has only value in the context of the request.

But when reading what your system does, I understand that the user wants to enter a twitter account and obtain a classification.  This is the only thing that is really of value for your user:

[image]

If it's the only use case, this diagram would be a little overkill.  Spontaneously, I'd suspect that a second use case could be: *train the classification engine* (as you have some ML component).

### Or is it about the details of your processing chain ?

If you want to represent the internals of the use case, i.e. the sequence of actions that are performed,  you may consider using an [activity diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams.html):

[image]

There are some advantages:  the processing flow is highlighted through the arrows. You can also show joins and forks in your processing flow.  You eventually can highlight what objects are exchanged between the process steps. ANd you don't need to go into technical details of the third party components (e.g. in a use case you'd show independent systems as actors, but not libraries).

Comment: Very good explanation covering the meaning I wanted to put a bit too shortly in my answer. The only thing to consider is that sequence diagram might actually better serve OP's purpose due to many parties involved.

Comment: @Ister Thank you ! I liked your short but correct answer, but considering frequent misunderstandings about use case, I felt it was necessary to develop further and stress that it's not just an opinion. To be honest, I was first tempted by the sequence diagrams, because they are a real option here. However, while they are certainly a part of the design, they require more precision about message exchanges, details which might not necessarily known at this stage. And personally I'd prefer to keep the unrelated interactions in separate diagrams (a kind of graphical separation of concerns).

Comment: +1 Use case diagrams are supposed to be a "table of contents" of the use cases (which are supposed to have value to the user), not the details of how they work. The details of the steps are in the *text* of the use case (not the use-case diagram) and could be supported by an activity diagram (as shown here).

Answer (score 4):

You should not decompose a use case like that. This is just a single simple use case "Request user's classification" with relatively many external systems as involved actors.

The decomposition to show how the use case is processed should be depicted on a separate diagram. I would suggest sequence diagram due to multiple interactions however activity diagram will also do (just might be less clear).